# google.visualisation.DataTable() merge rows

Tags: javascript, datatable, visualization, google-visualization

I have this data in a Google DataTable:

project1   |   system1   |   5
project2   |   system2   |   2
project1   |   system1   |   5
project3   |   system4   |   1

I need to merge rows that have the same projects and systems. So the result would be:

project1   |   system1   |  10
project2   |   system2   |  2
project3   |   system4   |  1

the number must be a sum of the values in the respective columns.

Is there a build in method in the DataTable to achieve this or can somebody give me a hint how to do this without the need of typical iterating through the table and comparing on each row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

populate your DataTable and use the group-Function for this: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group

Your example should fit into something like this:

```
var result = google.visualization.data.group(
  // input data
  your_data_table_obj,
  // key columns (columns to group by)
  [0, 1],
  // third column (index 2) will be summed
  [{'column': 2, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
);
```

One last thing: you are talking about Grouping not Merging. :-)